# What "Soft PLC" platforms are there out there

Tags: control-engineering

The Beckhoff TwinCAT system allows me to put a box on a DIN rail which can act as  a realtime PLC controller (programmed in Ladder or SF) while allowing a Windows instance to run in the hardware at the same time.  Hence a Windows program (eg a UI written in .NET, or a comple high level algorithm) can make API calls to exchange data with the realtime PLC program.

Are there other platforms out there which offer a similar sort of facility?  And how do they compare?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: I agree that the question is off-topic, but what is the advantage of running a PLC on a PC? Where is the I/O? What does it actually do besides Ethernet- or serial-based communication?